# Is there a way to find the 'date added' on a list that doesn't display that information?

Tags: html, inspect-element

This might not be the right place to ask this question, but on a site that lets you add items to a list and then sort by various criteria (name, price, availability, etc.), there's the option to sort by 'date added'. It sorts the list but doesn't actually show you the dates, which is what I'm specifically trying to obtain. So far looking through the html code using 'inspect element' doesn't work either. Since it's sorting the list correctly I assume there must be some where it's looking to find the correct order. Is there another way to look them up or any other thing I could try? I understand this is probably a very strange question.

Comment: depending on the implementation, it may not be possible

Comment: Look into the JS code to see what happens when you click on "sort by date". If the list is sorted on the client, there must be a data structure holding the date_added information.   If the sorting takes place on the server you are out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting can be done server side as well as client side. Depending on the method, if it is client side you should be able to see it in a variable stored in the JS/TS file.